# Why is .describe show the the descriptive statistic with exponents?

Tags: python, statistics, exponential, describe

[Descriptive Stats in Exponential form pix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPlsC.jpg)Hello there thanks in advance for reading.
I am probably making a mistake but I was wondering why when I try to get descriptive statistics it gives them in exponential form. This is quite cumbersome to read.
I have previously went through to remove the commas does that have anything to do with it.

I really would just like to have it present in plain interger form with no commas or decimals

I am sorry I didn't explain this well enough. This is my first post on stack and I am excited to be a part of the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using round:

```
df["column"].describe().round(1)
```

Scientific notation is used to display very large or small values, so probably this happened because of the range of your values

Comment: Aww I see Thank yoy so much that s works!